# What are the points to be kept in mind while porting c++ code from Linux to Windows?

Tags: c++, compilation, porting

I have started to port a project which involves C++, qt , MySql codes.These codes are written for Linux and I am porting them to Windows. So my question, are there any general points to be kept in mind while porting these codes from Linux to Windows? Please help me out here.

Comment: Many, start with paths, literals, magic numbers, includes.  I would read the book _C++ Gotchas_ to really master this

Comment: Windows goes out of its way to remain arbitrarily different, for example, the initial sockets support was a hack to approximate an industry standard (BSD), but hasn't been revised to eliminate the inconsistencies in the 20 years since.  Having to call funtions to initialise the IP subsystem, having a function to close sockets instead of being able use the same close function that works for file descriptors, differences in `poll`, different way to get an error code.  Still, that's less porting effort than Windows threads - totally non-standard.

Comment: @TonyDelroy "totally non-standard"... Well, the same could be said about someone going the other way around. Also remember that it wasn't _that_ long ago that things like threads was standardized in POSIX. And there are still several "standards" even on a POSIX platform: POSIX threads, C++11 standard library threads, and C11 standard library threads.

Comment: Well, you might well have trouble finding help at SO, Windows is fairly taboo in the [c++] tag.  Both Qt and MySql are cross-platform and available on Windows as well.  This should technically be only a recompile if you didn't stray too far from standard C++ and those libraries.  The compiler will tell you what kind of problems you'll need to solve.

Comment: Also, you should specify what compiler your are going to use. I haven't been actively developping C++ on windows for years now, but from my experience porting to Visual C++ was a pain whereas porting to mingw was a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on a sililar project, and what I have noted thus far is that the path names are different from Unix to Windows, the header files are not exactly the same between the two, and the size of variables are sometimes different. Here are some useful links as well:

http://www.willydev.net/descargas/prev/UNIX.pdf

http://suacommunity.com/dictionary/index.php

Comment: Hey, thanks alot. Those links are worth studying. thanks again : )

Comment: You are very welcome. I am currently working on the exact same thing, and I know it can be overwhelming!